# Why do we need to use association(multiplicity) in class diagrams?

Tags: class, uml

In my application, I have been working with class diagrams. Basically, I have drawn class diagrams for the business logic. Hibernate is used as data access layer. In most of the exmples of class diagrams, I've noticed that association(multiplicity) is considered in class diagrams.

I don't see any particular reason to use association(multiplicity) in class digarms, because we can't implement it on class. Can anybody explain why we need association with an example?

Comment: Why would you not want to see how your classes connect visually?! Keep in mind that unspecified multiplicity in UML means 1..1. If you are modeling unidirectional relationships like a relational database, you're losing the problem domain to the solution domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to omit multiplicity if it does not add valuable information to the model. However, there are cases different to your template where you want to model explicit multiplicity. Most often you find `0..1` (meaning an optional relation), `0..*` (an arbitrary number of relations) and `1..*` (one or many). E.g. for a person at work it may have `0..1` boss. A person may have `0..*` children. And one should have `1..*` friends ;-)

So as you see it depends on the domain whether you want to use multiplicity or not.

Answer (score 4):

(binary) Associations and Attributes are more or less the same thing in UML. You can choose to model with Association or with Attributes, or with a mix of the two.

I often use attributes when the type of the attribute is a DataType and associations when the type of the other end is a "regular" class. I've documented this best best practice on my website: [UML Best Practice: Attribute or Association](http://bellekens.com/2011/08/10/uml-best-practice-attribute-or-association/)

The advantage of using associations is that it shows the relations in a more visual way, making the relation often more obvious then with attributes.

Comment: yes but we don't implement the association(multiplicity). Only place, I can assume of using the (multiplicity) is in a data access layer but not in business layer.

Comment: Sure you do. Associations are usually implemented using Attributes. You can implement the additional constraints such as multiplicity as validation methods on the business objects, or you can leave that up to the database.

Comment: I wouldn't say binary associations and attributes are the same thing. An association essentially ties inverse properties together into one tidy bundle.

Comment: @JimL. That why I said _more or less_. There are a few differences, but those would probably take us too far. The main point here is to indicate that you can usually use one or the other to represent the same concept.

Comment: I agree, if you mean that a property can either be part of an association or not. Properties and associations are not more or less the same thing.

Comment: I think that OMG made a bad design decision in allowing both to exist without some hard connection. Tools like EA even make use of properties to define role names which introduces ambiguity. There should at least be a constraint for an XOR. But as Geert said: that would take us too far here. Probably worth a nice discussion on LinkedIn.